# Elegant solutions to non-conjugate buffer systems: ammonium carbonate, pyridinium dihydrogen phosphate, lysine and glutamic acid etc

Tags: equilibrium

Okay, this has really been frustrating me as a tutor because there is such few materials online on what to do in this case (besides use a brute-force method with systems of equations). Almost every pedagogical resource assumes a weak base and strong acid, or weak acid and strong base, and stops there. Oh, sometimes they will cover ammonium acetate, which is honestly cheating because pKa + pKb of both species add up to 14, so it's really a conjugate system in disguise. Is there a pedagogical resource for these general situations? I also realize my knowledge is lacking because I only was taught the system of equations method as a backup.